# AngularJS uib-datepicker doesn't display calendar after the first open/close event while in uib-tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

Versions:

- Bootstrap  3.5.5
- AngularJS  1.4.7
- AngularUIB 0.14.3

I'm using a uib-datepicker in a tabbed page (using uib-tabset)

```
<uib-tabset type='pills'>
  <uib-tab heading='HeatMap'>
    <input id='dateToImport' type='text' uib-datepicker-popup='yyyy-MM-dd' class='form-control' ng-change='changeDateTime()' ng-model='selectedDate' is-open='isDatePickerOpen' ng-click='openDatePicker($event)'/>
  </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Controller Code:

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, heatMapSvc){
  $scope.isDatePickerOpen = false;

  $scope.openDatePicker = function(){
    $scope.isDatePickerOpen = true;
    console.log("isDatePickerOpen?", $scope.isDatePickerOpen);
  };
});
```

When selecting the input, the datepicker calendar appears as expected.  Once I select a date, however, the datepicker calendar won't reappear on selection.  I've unfocused and refocused the control, nothing.  In my `openDatePicker` method call, I write to console to ensure that the method is getting called.  Every time I select the datepicker (regardless if the calendar appears), the controller is firing the correct method.

I've taken the datepicker out of the tabset that it was wrapped in, and the datepicker works correctly (shows the calendar every selection).  I need this datepicker to work correctly within the uib-tabset that I've defined.

Comment: Can you post your controller's code nevertheless?

Comment: @Daniel, I added the relevant snippets of the controller.  I work on a closed network, so copying large amounts of code gets tricky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is in "scope inheritance". Angular scopes is based on js objects prototype inheritance.

So... `$scope` <- `{ uib-tables scope }` <- `{ uib-tab scope }`
and at first time, { uib-tab scope } has not `isDatePickerOpen` property an it taken from $scope, but after poput is closed, `{ uib-tab scope }` will take own `isDatePickerOpen` than equal `false`, and the latter is more a priority. Function `openDatePicker` changing `$scope.isDatePickerOpen`, but calendar directive will take value from `{ uib-tab scope }`.

you can see it if will add `{{isDatePickerOpen}}` after `input` tag. After first time calendar opened it always wil be `false`.

**Solution**

*1) use `controllerAs` syntax.* **recommended**

controller:

```
  var vm = this;

  vm.isDatePickerOpen = false;

  vm.openDatePicker = function(){
    vm.isDatePickerOpen = true;
    console.log("isDatePickerOpen?", vm.isDatePickerOpen);
  };
```

template:

```
<uib-tabset type='pills'>
  <uib-tab heading='HeatMap'>
    <input id='dateToImport' type='text' uib-datepicker-popup='yyyy-MM-dd' class='form-control' ng-change='changeDateTime()' ng-model='selectedDate' is-open='vm.isDatePickerOpen' ng-click='vm.openDatePicker($event)'/>
  </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

**Note!** For using this solution you must using `controller as` syntax for declare a controller.

```
<body ng-controller="SettingsController1 as vm">
...
</body>
```

or if you use ui-router

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts', {
  templateUrl: '...',
  controller: function(){
    ...
  },
  controllerAs: 'vm'
})
```

*2) access to parent scope*. **not recommended** for information

controlller:

```
  $scope.isDatePickerOpen = false;

  $scope.openDatePicker = function(){
    $scope.isDatePickerOpen = true;
    console.log("isDatePickerOpen?", $scope.isDatePickerOpen);
  };
```

template:

```
<uib-tabset type='pills'>
  <uib-tab heading='HeatMap'>
    <input id='dateToImport' type='text' uib-datepicker-popup='yyyy-MM-dd' class='form-control' ng-change='changeDateTime()' ng-model='selectedDate' is-open='$parent.$parent.isDatePickerOpen' ng-click='openDatePicker($event)'/>
  </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

*3) use object*. **can be use**, but first sulution is better

controller:

```
  $scope.status = {isDatePickerOpen : false};

  $scope.openDatePicker = function(){
    $scope.status.isDatePickerOpen = true;
    console.log("isDatePickerOpen?", $scope.status.isDatePickerOpen);
  };
```

template:

```
<uib-tabset type='pills'>
  <uib-tab heading='HeatMap'>
    <input id='dateToImport' type='text' uib-datepicker-popup='yyyy-MM-dd' class='form-control' ng-change='changeDateTime()' ng-model='selectedDate' is-open='status.isDatePickerOpen' ng-click='openDatePicker($event)'/>
  </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

---

May be this article explain topic more detail.
http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: Your recommended solution didn't give the template visibility to the vm object.  I tried your third solution, and it worked just fine.  I'd like to keep working with you on the first solution to help other visitors, but I'm still going to mark this as accepted.  Thanks!

Comment: if `vm` doesn't exist, may be you don't use `controller as` syntax. I updated the first solution in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Got this working with the following:

```
<input id='dateToImport' type='text' uib-datepicker-popup='yyyy-MM-dd' class='form-control' ng-model='selectedDate' is-open='dateToImportIsOpen' ng-click='dateToImportIsOpen = !dateToImportIsOpen'/>
```

Note that dateToImportIsOpen will be written to current $scope.